# Multimerch 8 not sending order notification to seller with third party checkout

Tags: opencart, checkout, opencart2.3

I use multitmerch 8 on opencart 2.3.0.2 with journal 2 for my multivendor store. I recently installed the ajax best checkout extension by xtension.in. Everything seem fine on the checkout but I observed sellers are no longer notified of their product orders via emails as before only customers and admin get notification.

I believe the extension made some changes to the checkout files. I am not an expert in Opencart. Please I need help on how to restore the seller notification .

I see the following error in the log:

```
Undefined index: seller_text in /home/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_catalog_view_theme_journal2_template_mail_order.tpl on line 93
```

Thanks

Below is the xtension controller code at **\catalog\controller\extension\module\xtensions\checkout\checkout.php**

```php
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleXtensionsCheckoutCheckout extends Controller {
    public function country() {
        $json = array();

        $this->load->model('localisation/country');

        $country_info = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountry($this->request->get['country_id']);

        if ($country_info) {
            $this->load->model('localisation/zone');

            $json = array(
                'country_id'        => $country_info['country_id'],
                'name'              => $country_info['name'],
                'iso_code_2'        => $country_info['iso_code_2'],
                'iso_code_3'        => $country_info['iso_code_3'],
                'address_format'    => $country_info['address_format'],
                'postcode_required' => $country_info['postcode_required'],
                'zone'              => $this->model_localisation_zone->getZonesByCountryId($this->request->get['country_id']),
                'status'            => $country_info['status']      
            );
        }
        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
    public function customfield() {
        $json = array();

        // Customer Group
        if (isset($this->request->get['customer_group_id']) && is_array($this->config->get('config_customer_group_display')) && in_array($this->request->get['customer_group_id'], $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
            $customer_group_id = $this->request->get['customer_group_id'];
        } else {
            $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
        }

        $custom_fields = $this->xtensions_checkout->getXtensionsModel($this->config->get('xtensions_custom_fields_model_path'))->getCustomFields($customer_group_id);

        foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
            $json[] = array(
                'custom_field_id' => $custom_field['custom_field_id'],
                'required'        => $custom_field['required']
            );
        }

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
}
?>
```

Two multimerch vqmods files (I am not sure which is applicable here)
**multimerch_core.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE modification [
]>
<modification>
    <id>MultiMerch Digital Multivendor Marketplace Core</id>
    <author>http://multimerch.com/</author>

    <file name="system/engine/loader.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="after">
                $this->registry = $registry;
            </search>
            <add>
                $this->registry->set('MsLoader', \MsLoader::getInstance()->setRegistry($registry));
                $this->registry->set('ms_events', new \MultiMerch\Event\EventCollection());
                $this->registry->set('ms_event_manager', new \MultiMerch\Event\EventManager());
                $this->registry->set('MsHooks', new \MultiMerch\Core\Hook());
                $this->registry->set('MsEventManager', new \MultiMerch\Core\Event\EventManager());
                $this->registry->set('ms_logger', new \MultiMerch\Logger\Logger());
            </add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <!-- For OpenCart 2.2 and 2.3 -->
    <file name="system/framework.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                if ($config->has('action_pre_action')) {
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $res = $registry->get('db')->query("SELECT `value` FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE store_id = '0' AND `key`='msconf_config_seo_url_enable'");
                $pre_actions = $config->get('action_pre_action');
                foreach ($pre_actions as $key => $pre_action) {
                    if($pre_action == 'startup/seo_url' && $res->num_rows && $res->row['value'])
                        $pre_actions[$key] = 'startup/multimerch_seo_url';
                }
                $config->set('action_pre_action', $pre_actions);
            ]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                // Front Controller
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $registry->get('MsEventManager')->setRegistry($registry);
                $registry->get('MsHooks')->setRegistry($registry);
                $registry->get('MsHooks')->registerDefaultHooks();
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="system/library/template/php.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                final class PHP {
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                public function __get($key) {
                    return \MsLoader::getInstance()->getRegistry()->get($key);
                }

                public function __set($key, $value) {
                    \MsLoader::getInstance()->getRegistry()->set($key, $value);
                }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="system/library/cart/currency.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[public function format($number, $currency, $value = '', $format = true) {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[public function format($number, $currency = '', $value = '', $format = true) {]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[public function format]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if (!$currency)
                    $currency = \MsLoader::getInstance()->getRegistry()->get('config')->get('config_currency');
            ]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[public function has]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if (!$currency)
                    $currency = \MsLoader::getInstance()->getRegistry()->get('config')->get('config_currency');
            ]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[($currency)]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[($currency = '')]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[if (isset($this->currencies[$currency])) {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if (!$currency)
                    $currency = \MsLoader::getInstance()->getRegistry()->get('config')->get('config_currency');
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <!-- Enable "-" in routes -->
    <file name="system/engine/action.php,system/engine/loader.php,admin/controller/startup/router.php,catalog/controller/startup/router.php">
        <operation error="log">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\/]/', '', (string)$route)]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/]/', '', (string)$route)]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <!-- IE console fix -->
    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                <?php foreach ($scripts as $script) { ?>
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <?php if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) { ?>
                <script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}}; var msconf_account_pagination_limit = '<?php echo $this->config->get('msconf_account_pagination_limit'); ?>'; var config_language = <?php echo $dt_language; ?>; var msLanguageDefaults = { ms_account_product_shipping_elsewhere: "<?php echo $this->language->get('ms_account_product_shipping_elsewhere'); ?>"} </script>
            <?php } ?>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <!-- load common multimerch files -->
    <file name="catalog/controller/common/header.php">
        <operation error="log">
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                public function index() {
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                $data = array_merge(MsLoader::getInstance()->getRegistry()->get('load')->language('multiseller/multiseller'), isset($data) ? $data : array());

                MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->addStyle('multiseller');

                // note: renamed catalog
                $lang = "view/javascript/multimerch/datatables/lang/" . $this->config->get('config_language') . ".lng";
                $data['dt_language'] = file_exists(DIR_APPLICATION . $lang) ? "'catalog/$lang'" : "undefined";

                // Add complemented common.js
                $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/ms-common.js');

                $data['ms_seller_created'] = MsLoader::getInstance()->MsSeller->isCustomerSeller($this->customer->getId());
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <!-- Get order status id from database -->
    <file name="catalog/model/account/order.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT o.order_id, o.firstname, o.lastname, os.name as status, o.date_added, o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os ON (o.order_status_id = os.order_status_id) WHERE o.customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND o.order_status_id > '0' AND o.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY o.order_id DESC LIMIT " . (int)$start . "," . (int)$limit);
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT o.order_id, o.firstname, o.lastname, os.name as status, os.order_status_id, o.date_added, o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os ON (o.order_status_id = os.order_status_id) WHERE o.customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND o.order_status_id > '0' AND o.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY o.order_id DESC LIMIT " . (int)$start . "," . (int)$limit);
            } else {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT o.order_id, o.firstname, o.lastname, os.name as status, o.date_added, o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os ON (o.order_status_id = os.order_status_id) WHERE o.customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND o.order_status_id > '0' AND o.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY o.order_id DESC LIMIT " . (int)$start . "," . (int)$limit);
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                public function getOrder($order_id) {
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                public function getOrder($order_id, $type = NULL) {
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                $order_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND order_status_id > '0'");
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                if (empty($type)) {
                    $order_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND order_status_id > '0'");
                } elseif($type == 'seller') {
                    $order_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` AS o, `" . DB_PREFIX . "ms_order_product_data` AS m WHERE o.order_id = m.order_id AND o.order_id = " . (int)$order_id . " AND m.seller_id = " . (int)$this->customer->getId() . " AND o.order_status_id > '0'");
                }
            } else {
                $order_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND order_status_id > '0'");
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT op.*, opd.* FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "ms_order_product_data opd ON (op.order_id = opd.order_id AND op.product_id = opd.product_id AND op.order_product_id = opd.order_product_id) WHERE op.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
                if(empty($query->rows)) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
                }
            } else {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/account/order.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                foreach ($products as $product) {
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $ms_order_product_data = FALSE;
                if (MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                    $ms_order_product_data = $this->MsLoader->MsOrderData->getOrderData(array(
                        'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                        'order_id' => $product['order_id'],
                        'order_product_id' => $product['order_product_id'],
                        'single' => 1
                    ));
                    $this->load->language('multiseller/multiseller');
                }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                'reorder'  => $reorder,
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                'shipping_method' => !empty($ms_order_product_data['shipping_method']) ? " <i>(" . sprintf($this->language->get('mm_account_order_shipping_via'), $ms_order_product_data['shipping_method']) . ")</i>" : '',
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/account/order_info.tpl">
        <operation error="log">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                <?php echo $product['name']; ?>
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                <?php echo $product['name'] . " " . $product['shipping_method']; ?>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/common/footer.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                public function index() {
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $data = array_merge(MsLoader::getInstance()->getRegistry()->get('load')->language('multiseller/multiseller'), isset($data) ? $data : array());
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/footer.tpl">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
            <div id="powered"><?php echo $powered; ?></div>
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <div id="powered"><?php echo $powered; ?><?php echo $ms_footer; ?></div>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <!-- Disable the product if quantity is 0 -->
    <file name="catalog/model/checkout/order.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET quantity = (quantity - " . (int)$order_product['quantity'] . ") WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$order_product['product_id'] . "' AND subtract = '1'");
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                if ($this->config->get('msconf_disable_product_after_quantity_depleted')) {
                    $res = $this->db->query("SELECT quantity FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$order_product['product_id'] . "'");
                    if ((int)$res->row['quantity'] <= 0) {
                        MsLoader::getInstance()->MsProduct->changeStatus((int)$order_product['product_id'], MsProduct::STATUS_DISABLED);
                        MsLoader::getInstance()->MsProduct->disapprove((int)$order_product['product_id']);
                    }
                }
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                // Admin Alert Mail
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                $this->MsLoader->MsMail->sendOrderMails($order_id);
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <!-- Create product return instance for seller -->
    <!--<file name="catalog/controller/account/return.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after" offset="1"><![CDATA[
            $this->model_account_activity->addActivity('return_guest', $activity_data);
        ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
        $data = $this->request->post;
        $data['return_status_id'] = (int)$this->config->get('config_return_status_id');
        $data['seller_id'] = MsLoader::getInstance()->MsProduct->getSellerId($data['product_id']);

        $seller_return_id = MsLoader::getInstance()->MsReturn->createReturn($data);
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>-->

    <!-- Hide shipping calculations from cart if MM Vendor Shipping enabled. -->
    <file name="catalog/controller/extension/total/shipping.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                if ($this->config->get('shipping_status') && $this->config->get('shipping_estimator') && $this->cart->hasShipping()) {
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if ($this->config->get('shipping_status') && $this->config->get('shipping_estimator') && $this->cart->hasShipping() && (MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled() ? (int)$this->config->get('msconf_shipping_type') !== 2 : true)) {
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                if (!isset($this->session->data['shipping_method'])) {
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled() && (int)$this->config->get('msconf_shipping_type') == 2) {
                    foreach($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
                        if (!isset($this->session->data['ms_cart_product_shipping']['fixed'][$product['product_id']]) && !isset($this->session->data['ms_cart_product_shipping']['combined'][$product['product_id']]) && !isset($this->session->data['ms_cart_product_shipping']['free'][$product['product_id']])) {
                            $redirect = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', true);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (!isset($this->session->data['shipping_method'])) {
            ]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(isset($this->session->data['ms_cart_product_shipping']))
                unset($this->session->data['ms_cart_product_shipping']);

            if(isset($this->session->data['ms_coupons']))
                unset($this->session->data['ms_coupons']);
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/checkout/success.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                unset($this->session->data['totals']);
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(isset($this->session->data['ms_cart_product_shipping']))
                unset($this->session->data['ms_cart_product_shipping']);

            if(isset($this->session->data['ms_coupons']))
                unset($this->session->data['ms_coupons']);
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <!-- add mm mail to customer before $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/return/success', '', true)); -->
    <file name="catalog/controller/account/return.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                public function add() {
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                if(isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
                    $this->session->data['return_product_id'] = $this->request->get['product_id'];
                }
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/return/success', '', true));
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                // get product seller's email
                if(isset($this->session->data['return_product_id'])) {
                    $seller_id = MsLoader::getInstance()->MsProduct->getSellerId($this->session->data['return_product_id']);
                    unset($this->session->data['return_product_id']);

                    if($seller_id) {
                        $seller_email = MsLoader::getInstance()->MsSeller->getSellerEmail($seller_id);
                        if($seller_email) {
                            $this->load->language('multiseller/multiseller');
                            $serviceLocator = MsLoader::getInstance()->load('\MultiMerch\Module\MultiMerch')->getServiceLocator();
                            $mailTransport = $serviceLocator->get('MailTransport');
                            $mails = new \MultiMerch\Mail\Message\MessageCollection();

                            $MailProductReturned = $serviceLocator->get('MailProductReturned', false)
                                ->setTo($seller_email)
                                ->setData(array(
                                    'product_name' => $this->request->post['product'],
                                    'store_name' => $this->config->get('config_name')
                                ));

                            $mails->add($MailProductReturned);
                            $mailTransport->sendMails($mails);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/account/register.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                // Add to activity log
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                $this->ms_events->add(new \MultiMerch\Event\Event(array(
                    'customer_id' => $this->customer->getId(),
                    'event_type' => \MultiMerch\Event\Event::CUSTOMER_CREATED,
                    'data' => array()
                )));

                if($this->ms_events->count()) {
                    $this->ms_event_manager->create($this->ms_events);
                }
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <!--<file name="admin/controller/setting/setting.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if($this->request->post['config_language'] && $this->session->data['language'] !== $this->request->post['config_language']) {
                    $this->session->data['language'] = $this->request->post['config_language'];
                }
            ]]></add>

        </operation>
    </file>-->

    <file name="catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php">
        <operation error="log">
            <search position="before" index="1"><![CDATA[
                if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if ($result['code'] === 'mm_shipping_total')
                    continue;
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

and the other vqmod file **multimerch_core_transactions.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE modification [
]>
<modification>
    <id>MultiMerch Core Transactions</id>
    <author>http://multimerch.com/</author>

    <!-- transactions for order -->
    <file name="catalog/model/checkout/order.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[return $order_id;]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled())
                $this->MsLoader->MsTransaction->createMsOrderDataEntries($order_id);
            ]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                $this->db->query("UPDATE `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` SET order_status_id = '" . (int)$order_status_id . "', date_modified = NOW() WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled())
                $this->MsLoader->MsTransaction->createMsOrderBalanceEntries($order_id, $order_status_id);
            ]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                if (!in_array($order_info['order_status_id'], array_merge($this->config->get('config_processing_status')
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                $event_exists = $this->ms_event_manager->getEvents(array(
                    'event_type' => \MultiMerch\Event\Event::ORDER_CREATED,
                    'data' => json_encode(array('order_id' => (int)$order_id)),
                    'single' => 1
                ));

                if(empty($event_exists)) {
                    $this->ms_events->add(new \MultiMerch\Event\Event(array(
                        'customer_id' => $this->customer->getId(),
                        'event_type' => \MultiMerch\Event\Event::ORDER_CREATED,
                        'data' => array('order_id' => (int)$order_id)
                    )));
                }

                if($this->ms_events->count()) {
                    $this->ms_event_manager->create($this->ms_events);
                }
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <!-- Fix admin order edit -->
    <file name="catalog/controller/api/order.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                $this->model_checkout_order->editOrder($order_id, $order_data);
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled())
                $this->MsLoader->MsTransaction->adminUpdateMsOrderDataEntries($order_id);
            ]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                $this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory($order_id,
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                $transactions = $this->MsLoader->MsTransaction->createMsOrderBalanceEntries($order_id, $this->request->post['order_status_id']);

                $transaction_ids = [];
                foreach($transactions as $transaction_id) {
                    if($transaction_id) $transaction_ids[] = $transaction_id;
                }

                $suborders = $this->MsLoader->MsSuborder->getSuborders(array(
                    'order_id' => $order_id
                ));

                $sellers_suborders_info = array();
                foreach($suborders as $suborder) {
                    $sellers_suborders_info[] = $suborder['seller'] . ' (#' . $order_id . '-' . $suborder['suborder_id']. ')';
                }

                $this->load->language('multiseller/multiseller');
                $json['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('ms_order_success_suborders_modified'), $order_id, implode(', ', $sellers_suborders_info));

                if(!empty($transaction_ids)) {
                    $json['success'] .= ' ' . sprintf($this->language->get('ms_order_success_transactions_created'), implode(', ', $transaction_ids));
                }
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="replace" index="5"><![CDATA[
                $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(!MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="admin/view/template/marketing/coupon_form.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                <div class="panel panel-default">
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <?php if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                    <?php echo MsLoader::getInstance()->getRegistry()->get('language')->get('ms_fixed_coupon_warning'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="admin/view/template/sale/voucher_form.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                <div class="panel panel-default">
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <?php if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                    <?php echo MsLoader::getInstance()->getRegistry()->get('language')->get('ms_voucher_warning'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="admin/view/template/sale/voucher_list.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                <div class="panel panel-default">
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <?php if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                    <?php echo MsLoader::getInstance()->getRegistry()->get('language')->get('ms_voucher_warning'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/extension/total/coupon.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                $this->response->addHeader
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                if(isset($coupon_info["type"]) AND $coupon_info["type"] == "F"){
                    unset($json['redirect']);
                    unset($this->session->data['success']);
                    unset($this->session->data['coupon']);
                    $this->load->language('multiseller/multiseller');
                    $json['error'] = $this->language->get('ms_error_fixed_coupon_warning');
                }
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/extension/total/voucher.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                $this->response->addHeader
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                unset($json['redirect']);
                unset($this->session->data['success']);
                unset($this->session->data['voucher']);
                $this->load->language('multiseller/multiseller');
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('ms_error_voucher_warning');
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <!-- MultiMerch Discount coupons -->
    <file name="catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$result = $this->load->controller('extension/total/' . basename($file, '.php'));]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $ms_controller_path = 'extension/total/' . basename($file, '.php');

                if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled() && $this->config->get('msconf_allow_seller_coupons') && (string)basename($file, '.php') === 'coupon') {
                    $ms_controller_path = 'multimerch/cart_coupon';
                }

                $result = $this->load->controller($ms_controller_path);
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a conflict between **multitmerch 8** and "best checkout extension by xtension". There should be something you have to add to code of **xtension** controller. This "something" should be in a vqmod file or **multitmerch 8** (some part that add changes to standard opencart checkout). There should be added rule for **xtension** controller.

Cant tell you more. Please, add to you question a code of **multitmerch 8** vqmod and **xtension** controller. And a link to a live site.

Comment: I've added the codes as requested, please kindly take a look

Answer (score 0):

multimerch_core.xml ... This part of code must be for email sends:

```
<file name="catalog/model/checkout/order.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                // Admin Alert Mail
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if(MsLoader::getInstance()->MsHelper->isInstalled()) {
                $this->MsLoader->MsMail->sendOrderMails($order_id);
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
```

Check carefully vqmod cache file: /home/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_checkout_order.php that modification is installed at this file...

This error is result of other vqmod modification... There are no code for this in vqmod mofications that you show

```
Undefined index: seller_text in /home/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_catalog_view_theme_journal2_template_mail_order.tpl on line 93
```

Comment: I checked /home/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_checkout_order.php the code area you highlighted typically alerts the admin. I'm looking out for where the seller notification is triggered and where to include in xtension module

Answer (score 0):

The following is the code at the install.xml for the xtension module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Xtensions-Best Checkout and Customer FrameWork</name>
    <version>Module_Version_5.0_OC_V_2.3.x.x</version>
    <code>xtensions_best_checkout</code>
    <file path="admin/controller/customer/custom_field.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA['sort_order'      => $result['sort_order'],]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
                'edit_custom'     => $this->url->link($this->config->get('xtensions_custom_fields_path').'/edit', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&custom_field_id=' . $result['custom_field_id'] . $url, 'SSL'),
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$data['button_edit'] = $this->language->get('button_edit');]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
                $data['button_edit_custom'] = $this->language->get('button_edit_custom');
                $data['button_add_custom'] = $this->language->get('button_add_custom');
                $data['add_custom'] = $this->url->link($this->config->get('xtensions_custom_fields_path').'/add', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL');
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="admin/language/*/customer/custom_field.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<?php]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
                $_['button_edit_custom']                = 'Edit using Xtensions Custom Fields';
                $_['button_add_custom']                 = 'Add New using Xtensions Custom Fields';
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="admin/view/template/customer/custom_field_list.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<td class="text-right"><a href="<?php echo $custom_field['edit']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_edit; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
                <td class="text-right"><a href="<?php echo $custom_field['edit_custom']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_edit_custom; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $button_edit_custom; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $custom_field['edit']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_edit; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<div class="pull-right"><a href="<?php echo $add; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_add; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
                <div class="pull-right"><a href="<?php echo $add_custom; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_add_custom; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <?php echo $button_add_custom; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $add; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_add; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="admin/view/template/sale/order_invoice.tpl">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[<?php echo $order['payment_address']; ?>]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
            <?php if($order['customer_fields']){ echo '<br/>'; ?>
                <?php foreach ($order['customer_fields'] as $field){?>
                    <?php echo $field?'<br/>'.$field:''; ?>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="admin/view/template/sale/order_shipping.tpl">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[<?php echo $order['telephone']; ?>]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
                <?php foreach ($order['customer_fields'] as $field){?>
                    <?php echo $field?'<br/>'.$field:''; ?>
                <?php } ?>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="admin/controller/sale/order.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[$data['products'] = array();]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
        //xtensions- Custom Fields
            if($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$order_info['store_id'])){
                $formatted_address = $this->xtensions_checkout->getXtensionsModel($this->config->get('xtensions_custom_fields_path'))->getFormattedAddressForOrder($order_info);
                $data['payment_address'] = $formatted_address['payment_address_formatted'];
                $data['shipping_address'] = $formatted_address['shipping_address_formatted'];
            }
            //xtensions- Custom Fields
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[$product_data = array();]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
        //xtensions- Custom Fields
                $customer_fields =array();
                if($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$order_info['store_id'])){
                    $customer_fields =array();
                    $fieldData = $this->xtensions_checkout->getXtensionsModel($this->config->get('xtensions_custom_fields_path'))->getCustomFieldByIdentifier($order_info['custom_field'],'account');
                    foreach($this->xtensions_checkout->getXtensionsModel($this->config->get('xtensions_custom_fields_path'))->getCustomFieldsAll($order_info['customer_group_id']) as $field){
                        if($field['location']=='account' && $field['invoice']){
                            if(isset($fieldData[$field['identifier']])){
                                $customer_fields[] = $fieldData[$field['identifier']];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $formatted_address = $this->xtensions_checkout->getXtensionsModel($this->config->get('xtensions_custom_fields_path'))->getFormattedAddressForOrder($order_info);
                    $payment_address = $formatted_address['payment_address_formatted'];
                    $shipping_address = $formatted_address['shipping_address_formatted'];
                }
                //xtensions- Custom Fields
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA['order_id'        => $order_id,]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
        //xtensions- Custom Fields
        'customer_fields'    => $customer_fields,
        //xtensions- Custom Fields
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="admin/controller/startup/startup.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$this->registry->set('cart', new Cart\Cart($this->registry));]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        $xtensions_checkout = new XtensionsCheckout($this->registry);
            $this->registry->set('xtensions_checkout', $xtensions_checkout);
                ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/controller/startup/startup.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$this->registry->set('cart', new Cart\Cart($this->registry));]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        $xtensions_checkout = new XtensionsCheckout($this->registry);
            $this->registry->set('xtensions_checkout', $xtensions_checkout);
                ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/model/account/customer.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$address_id = $this->db->getLastId();]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        if($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$this->config->get('config_store_id')) && isset($data['noaddress']) && $data['noaddress']){
                $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "address WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "' AND address_id ='".$address_id. "'");
                $address_id = 0;
            }
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/controller/account/address.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[public function add() {]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        if($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$this->config->get('config_store_id'))){
                $this->response->setOutput($this->load->controller($this->config->get('xtensions_account_controller_path').'address/add', '', 'SSL'));
                return '';
            }
      ]]></add>
        </operation>
    <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[public function edit() {]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        if($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$this->config->get('config_store_id'))){
                $this->response->setOutput($this->load->controller($this->config->get('xtensions_account_controller_path').'address/edit', '', 'SSL'));
                return '';
            }
      ]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$data['add'] = $this->url->link('account/address/add', '', true);]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
        if($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$this->config->get('config_store_id'))){
            $data['addresses'] = $this->load->controller($this->config->get('xtensions_account_controller_path').'address/addresses');
        }
      ]]></add>
        </operation>  
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/controller/checkout/checkout.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('checkout/checkout', $data));]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
        // Xtensions Best Checkout
            if ($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout', $this->config->get('config_store_id'))) {
                $data += $this->load->language($this->config->get('xtensions_language_path'));
                $data['xtensions_controller_path'] = $this->config->get('xtensions_controller_path');
                $data['xheader'] = $this->load->controller($data['xtensions_controller_path'].'xheader');
                $data['xfooter'] = $this->load->controller($data['xtensions_controller_path'].'xfooter');
                $data['xcvc'] = $this->load->controller($data['xtensions_controller_path'].'xcvc');

                $modData = $this->xtensions_checkout->getXtensionsData($this->config->get('config_store_id'), 'xtensions_best_checkout');
                $data['custom_js'] = isset($modData['xconfig']['design']['js']) ? html_entity_decode($modData['xconfig']['design']['js'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') : '';
                $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('xtensions_view_path').'xcheckout.tpl', $data));
                // Xtensions Best Checkout
            } else {
                $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('checkout/checkout', $data));
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[$this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment.js');]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
        if ($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout', $this->config->get('config_store_id'))) {
            // $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment.js'); - Included by Xtensions
        } else {
             $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment.js');
        }
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[$this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js');]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
        if ($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout', $this->config->get('config_store_id'))) {
                // $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js'); - Included by Xtensions
            } else {
                $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js');
            }
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[$this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css');]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
        if ($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout', $this->config->get('config_store_id'))) {
                // $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css'); - Included by Xtensions
            } else {
                $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css');
            }
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('checkout/confirm', $data));]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
        // Xtensions Best Checkout
        $xconfig = $this->xtensions_checkout->getXtensionsData($this->config->get('config_store_id'), 'xtensions_best_checkout');
        $misc_options = $xconfig['xconfig']['options'];
        if(isset($misc_options['payment']['content'][$this->session->data['payment_method']['code']][$this->config->get('config_language_id')])){
            $data['before_content'] = html_entity_decode($misc_options['payment']['content'][$this->session->data['payment_method']['code']][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }else{
            $data['before_content'] = '';
        }
        if ($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout', $this->config->get('config_store_id'))) {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('xtensions_view_path').'xconfirm.tpl', $data));
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('checkout/confirm', $data));
        }
        // Xtensions Best Checkout
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$this->session->data['order_id'] = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($order_data);]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
        // Xtensions Best Checkout
            $data['isBestActive'] = $this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$this->config->get('config_store_id'));
            if(!isset($this->session->data['order_id']) || !$this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$this->config->get('config_store_id'))){
                $this->session->data['order_id'] = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($order_data);
            }else{
                $this->model_checkout_order->editOrder($this->session->data['order_id'],$order_data);
                $this->xtensions_checkout->getXtensionsModel($this->config->get('xtensions_custom_fields_model_path'))->editOrderXtensions($this->session->data['order_id'],$order_data);
            }
            // Xtensions Best Checkout
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/model/checkout/order.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA['order_id'                => $order_query->row['order_id'],]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        // Xtensions Best Checkout
                    'customer_group_id'       => $order_query->row['customer_group_id'],
        // Xtensions Best Checkout
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[$data['ip'] = $order_info['ip'];]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        // Xtensions Best Checkout
                $data['customer_fields'] = array();
                if($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$this->config->get('config_store_id'))){

                    $fieldData = $this->xtensions_checkout->getXtensionsModel($this->config->get('xtensions_custom_fields_model_path'))->getCustomFieldByIdentifier($order_info['custom_field'],'account');
                    foreach($this->xtensions_checkout->getXtensionsModel($this->config->get('xtensions_custom_fields_model_path'))->getCustomFields($order_info['customer_group_id']) as $field){
                        if($field['location']=='account' && $field['email_display']){
                            if(isset($fieldData[$field['identifier']])){
                                $data['customer_fields'][] = array('name'=>$field['name'],'value'=>$fieldData[$field['identifier']]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Xtensions Best Checkout
      ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[$data['products'] = array();]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
        // Xtensions Best Checkout
                if($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$this->config->get('config_store_id'))){
                    $formatted_address = $this->xtensions_checkout->getXtensionsModel($this->config->get('xtensions_custom_fields_model_path'))->getFormattedAddressForOrder($order_info);
                    $data['payment_address'] = $formatted_address['payment_address_formatted'];
                    $data['shipping_address'] = $formatted_address['shipping_address_formatted'];
                }
                // Xtensions Best Checkout
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/mail/order.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<b><?php echo $text_ip; ?></b> <?php echo $ip; ?><br />]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
        <?php foreach ($customer_fields as $field){?>
            <?php if($field['value']){ ?>
                    <b><?php echo $field['name']; ?></b> <?php echo $field['value']; ?><br />
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
      ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/controller/account/order.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[$data['shipping_method'] = $order_info['shipping_method'];]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
        //xtensions- Custom Fields
            if($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$this->config->get('config_store_id'))){
                $formatted_address = $this->xtensions_checkout->getXtensionsModel($this->config->get('xtensions_custom_fields_model_path'))->getFormattedAddressForOrder($order_info);
                $data['payment_address'] = $formatted_address['payment_address_formatted'];
                $data['shipping_address'] = $formatted_address['shipping_address_formatted'];
            }
            //xtensions- Custom Fields
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/controller/account/edit.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[public function index() {]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        if($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$this->config->get('config_store_id'))){
                $this->response->setOutput($this->load->controller($this->config->get('xtensions_account_controller_path').'edit', '', 'SSL'));
                return '';
            }
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/controller/account/register.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[public function index() {]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        if($this->xtensions_checkout->isActive('xtensions_best_checkout',$this->config->get('config_store_id'))){
                $this->response->setOutput($this->load->controller($this->config->get('xtensions_account_controller_path').'register', '', 'SSL'));
                return;
            }
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```